# How do I accommodate all the information in one table cell in my iphone application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

In my table cell I have long line of information and because of that I'm not able to show all the information properly. I tried to make the table cell's hight big but that didn't help.
below is the image of the table cell where you can not see the rest of the information.
[image: Table row with trimmed info]

Thanks

Mayur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take Custom cell and inside the same,take UILabel with the property of word wrap with [Linebreakmode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html).Remember to take numberOfLines to 0. Hope that Helps you.

Comment: Thanks Sarah I ll surely try this.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Create a `CustomCell` inheriting `UITableView` class and set the size of the cell to the size of custom cell and to get multiple lines you can also set `linebreakmode` :

```
   lblName.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; 
    lblName.numberOfLines = 2; //Specify Number Of Lines
```